# SQL Access help in sum from 2 different tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have these tables

```
table 1

id      price
1       30
2       40
3       50


table 2

    id      price
    1       70
    2       5
    3       10
```

i want a query that would sum the the `price` value based on the `ID`
like if table1.id=table2.id then sum table1.price and table2.price
the end result should be something like this

```
table 3

    id      price
    1       100
    2       45
    3       60
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can;

```
SELECT 
  TABLE1.ID, 
  TABLE1.PRICE+TABLE2.PRICE
FROM TABLE1 
  INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID;
```

Or if there are duplicate IDs in either table;

```
SELECT 
  TABLE1.ID, 
  SUM(TABLE1.PRICE+TABLE2.PRICE)
FROM TABLE1 
  INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
  GROUP BY TABLE1.ID;
```

Comment: instead of just "+" can i use more complex math operation?
like sum(TABLE1.PRICE*100/TABLE2.PRICE)
would it work?

Comment: never mind i will try it and see if it works :) i don't need to be lazy